# reorder and save UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I parse data from a server which contains passengers details.
the passengers details are saved into Passenger class.
The main viewController contains a UITableView which loads the passengers data and allows the user to rearrange the cells order.

My question is how can I save the tables new order and load it again each time the app starts, but with new passenger details parsed from the server.
I prefer not use core data.

Here is the code:

### Passenger.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Passenger : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
    NSString *code;
    NSString *country;
    NSString *date;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *code;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *country;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *date;
```

### mainViewController m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    NSString *stringToMove = passengersArray[sourceIndexPath.row];
    [passengersArray removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [passengersArray insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    Passenger *current = [passengersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        nameLabel.text = current.name;        
        UILabel *codeLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
        codeLabel.text = current.code;    
        UILabel *countryLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
        countryLabel.text = current.country;    
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the passenger list from a plist in form of an Array. And when you update the information you iterate through that plist array, compare, update and add new passengers to the list. Once the user has rearranged the order you save it to the plist.

### Fetch

```
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSString *errorDesc;

NSString * plistPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
plistPath = [plistPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Passengers.plist"];

NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
NSArray *temp = (NSArray *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                      propertyListFromData:plistXML
                                    mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                      format:&format
                                      errorDescription:&errorDesc];
```

### Save

```
NSString *error;
NSString *plistPath;

NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Passengers.plist"];

NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:_passengersArray format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
if(plistData)
{
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error writing passengers to file %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my main problem was to compare and update the data, but After I managed to do that, I saved the order in nsuserdefaults and that works for me.

Comment: Hi how can i load the reordered indexpath when app launched.